# Android Emulator get port Number

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

The port for emulator 5554 is not working when I try to type the command:  `telnet localhost 5554`

The error is:

```
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5554: 
Connect failed
```

How could it connect to port 5554 to let the android emulator sending socket, and the android emulator program on client server side give a message that does not work ( unfortunately client has stopped)

Comment: call `netstat -na | grep 5554` if you use linux/mac. On windows try `netstat -na` and check manually if the port is open

Comment: The Firewall state is on, and I check the netstat -na command, the port number 5554 not exist in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your port is open or not using this link.
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
If u have personal firewall try disabling that.